# ui-router state controller has undefined ng-models in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to manipulate some input date through a controller injected with ui-router but i'm not clear on how the scope should work in this case.

I attach my example scenario:

Template html

```
<div class="date-filter-gallery">
  <input type="date" ng-model="date.start">
  <input type="date" ng-model="date.end">
</div>
```

Ui-router

```
.state('stationGallery', {
  url: '/station-gallery/{stationId}',
  templateUrl: 'src/templates/station-detail.template.html',
  controller: 'StationGalleryController as sg',
  resolve: {
    images: ['$stateParams', 'WeatherStationsService', function ($stateParams, WeatherStationsService) {
      return WeatherStationsService.getImagesByStation($stateParams.stationId);
    }]
  }
});
```

Controller

```
StationGalleryController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function StationGalleryController($scope) {
  let sg = this;
  $scope.date.start = new Date(2017,1,1);
  $scope.date.end = new Date(2017,2,1);
}
```

$scope.date is undefined

I apologyze for the question but i'm new to angular and JS world.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate `$scope.date` object first. For instance:

```
$scope.date = {};
$scope.date.start = new Date(2017,1,1);
$scope.date.end = new Date(2017,2,1);
```

Or if you prefer:

```
$scope.date = {
    'start': new Date(2017,1,1),
    'end': new Date(2017,2,1)
}
```

Comment: tnx, so basic js issue.. what a dumb :D